# Extract multiple variable values from a single regular expression

Tags: regex, jmeter

I want to extract ID and Name from a single regular expression, but I'm not able to get the correct response

```
<a href="/profiles/6635/Name"
```

I have used below regular expression

```
<a href="/profiles/(.*?)/(.*?)"
```

Comment: You must replace `.*?` with `[^/]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @WiktorStribiżew suggested, you should fix your regular expression to

```
<a href="/profiles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)"
```

But also use `$1$` and `$2$` to get both values in in Template field, for example

```
$1$$2$
```

Will save to variable concatenated value - `6635Name`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used the same expression but in request it is fetching 8204Name but ideally a request should be processed as 8204/name

Comment: @VikasDhiman you can change Template to `$1$/$2$` to accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

What you use `<a href="/profiles/(.*?)/(.*?)"` is fine to capture `ID` and `name` from `<a href="/profiles/6635/Name"` because a lazy way (non-greedy) `(.*?)` you use will match only between `profiles/`  and the second `/` same like using `[^\/]+` and then between `/` and `"` so , check again that you put everything right .

You may need to escape `/`  like this `\/`so , change it to :

```
<a href="\/profiles\/(.*?)\/(.*?)"
```

This is your same regex here [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/29EPaG/4)

And if you need to make sure with java tester use this tool :[Java regex tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have used the same expression but in request it is fetching 8204Name but ideally a request should be processed as 8204/name